# Qualifying an inner trait's method so that it is private from the outside but accessible from the inside

Tags: scala, private, traits

I would like to qualify a method of an inner trait so that it can only be accessed by subclasses of the outer trait. E.g.:

```
trait Tree[A] {
  trait TNode {
    final def prevOption: Option[TNode] = Option(prev)
    protected[Tree] def prev: TNode // !
  }

  def test(n: TNode): Option[TNode] = Option(n.prev)
}
```

How can I modify the qualifiers of `prev`, so that the following **does** compile:

```
trait TreeImpl[A] extends Tree[A] {
  def test2(n: TNode): Option[TNode] = Option(n.prev)
}
```

While this **does not** compile:

```
def test3[A](t: Tree[A]#TNode) = t.prev
```

(that is to say, a public `def prev: TNode` is not an option).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems as if this is not possible.

A possible workaround is a protected accessor method on Tree, like so (I removed some stuff, to make code clearer):

```
trait Tree {
    trait TNode {
        private[Tree] def prev : TNode
    }
    protected final def prevAccessor(n: TNode) = n.prev
    def test( n: TNode ) = n.prev
}

trait TreeImpl extends Tree {
    def test2( n: TNode ) = prevAccessor(n)
}
```